# Launch synchronized console application from Access 2003

Tags: windows, ms-access

I know that, to launch an application from access 2003, you just need to use 'shell' command, but I need help with some extra behaviours:

1.- It's a console application

2.- I need to pass a path as parameter, and it uses ""

3.- Application should be somehow 'modal':

---> Access must WAIT for the console application to end

---> If possible, not abasolutely necessary, console window should be visible, so we can read the messages.

---> If possible, not necessary, I would like to interact with the console application (accepts keypresses)

4.- Could Access read the application ExitCode?

¿Could you help me, please? I really need this code... :(

Thanks! :)

**EDIT(Solved)**

First of all, sorry for asking, but I was in a real hurry, and you are allways so FAST... :) Posted my solution as answer.

Comment: Have you made any effort to do this yourself? We're not a code writing service, where you post your requirements and someone churns out the code to meet them.

Comment: @Ken Sorry, guys. I was only trying to explain my problem in detail, so you could completely understand my case. I have edited my question, and added how I resolved the problem of writing the shell string with quotes. What I need is access to wait for console apllication end and get return code. How? Just need the idea, I'll code it :)

Comment: @Ken Finally solved. \o/ ! I posted the answer. Sorry for bothering :( . I was in a hurry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, sorry for asking, but I was in a real hurry, and you are allways so FAST... :)

Here is the solution

**- Quotes in strings**

To specify a quotes you need to 'double it'. So:

To create a string with quotes, you must specify:

```
coutesInString = """"
```

To create the string "C:\My Documents\" it should be:

```
mypath= """C:\My Documents\"""
```

To launch my console application with parameters, it could be a sort of this:

```
binPath = "c:\My Program\program.exe"
sourceFile = "c:\My Data\soucefile.dat"
shellString = """" & binPath & """" & " -sourcce " & """" & sourcefile & """"
shell shellstring, 1
```

**- Waiting for shell to end and get return code**

Dont use 'shell' command. Create a WshShell object and launch it.

```
Dim wsh as Object
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean
Dim returnCode As Integer

waitOnReturn = True
Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
returnCode = wsh.Run(shellString, vbNormalFocus, waitOnReturn)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0004.htm

API: Shell and Wait, Terry Kreft
(Q) Whenever I shell out to another application, Access doesn't seem to wait before executing the next VBA statment. How do I make Access wait till I'm done with my other application.
(A) Paste the following code in a new module and use the Shell sub.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll keep in mind :) Anyway, I think i'll keep using the WshShell, as it doesn't require to add extra code.